# Separate log file for separate thread using serilog

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have a .Net Worker Service app which has multiple threads. I want to log each thread into separate file to make it easier to read the logs. Any ideas to implement this?

Comment: Personally, id just sink to a proper log aggregator like SEQ or anything else. Structure your logs the way you want, and never worry about files again unless its backup

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common way of deciding which sink to write to at run-time is to use the [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map):

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Map(_ => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
        (threadId, wt) => wt.File($"log-{threadId}.log"))
.CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Hello from the main thread");

var task1 = Task.Run(() => Log.Information("Hello from thread X"));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => Log.Information("Hello from thread Y"));

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

You should consider [limiting the number of open sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map#limiting-the-number-of-open-sinks) when using this approach.